# scala: abstract classes instantiation?

Tags: scala, abstract-class

How it comes that I instantiate an abstract class?

```
  abstract class A {
    val a: Int
  }

  val a = new A {val a = 3}
```

Or is some concrete class implicitly created? And what do those braces after `new A` mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With this, you implicitly extend `A`. What you did is syntactic sugar, equivalent to this:

```
class A' extends A {
    val a = 3
}
val a = new A'
```

These brackets merely let you extend a class on the fly, creating a new, anonymous class, which instantiates the value `a` and is therefore not abstract any more.

Answer (score 7):

If you know Java, this is similar to:

```
new SomeAbstractClass() {
    // possible necessary implementation
}
```

Due to Scalas [uniform access](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/learning-scala-uniform-access-principle) it looks like you're not implementing any abstract functions, but just by giving `a` a value, you actually do "concretesize" the class.

In other words, you're creating an instance of a **concrete subclass of `A`** without giving the subclass a name (thus the term "anonymous" class).

Answer (score 4):

you're instantiating an anonymous class that inherits from A and overloads its abstract a member.
For reference, see the part about anonymous class instantiations in [A Tour of Scala: Abstract Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/105)

Answer (score 3):

Scala allows you to create not only anonymous functions but anonymous classes too.

What you have done is simular to

```
class Anon extends A {
  val a = 3
}
```

but without `Anon` name