# scala's type checker doesn't recognize types in abstract path-dependent classes scenario

Tags: scala, types

Let's define a trait with an abstract class

```
object Outer {

  trait X {
    type T
    val empty: T
  }
```

Now we can make an instance of it:

```
  val x = new X {
    type T = Int
    val empty = 42
  }
```

Scala now recognizes, that `x.empty` is an `Int`:

```
  def xEmptyIsInt = x.empty: Int
```

Now, let's define an other class

```
  case class Y(x: X) extends X {
    type T = x.T
    val empty = x.empty
  }
```

and make an instance of it

```
  val y = Y(x)
```

But now Scala, isn't able to infer that `y.empty` is of type `Int`. The following

```
  def yEmptyIsInt = y.empty: Int
```

now produces an error message:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : y.x.T
required: Int
       y.empty : Int
```

Why is this the case? Is this a scala bug?

We can mitigate this issue by introducing a parameters to the case class:

```
  case class Z[U](x: X { type T = U }) extends X {
    type T = U
    val empty = x.empty
  }
```

Then it works again

```
  val z = Z(x)
  def zEmptyIsInt: Int = z.empty
```

But we always have to mention all the types inside X at call-site. This ideally should be an implementation detail which leads to the following approach:

```
  case class A[U <: X](z: U) extends X {
    type T = z.T
    val empty = z.empty
  }
```

This also mitigates the issue

```
  val a = A(x)
  def aEmptyIsInt: Int = a.empty

}
```

So, to summarize, my questions are the following: Why does the simple case doesn't work? Is this a valid workaround? What other problems might come up when we follow one of the two workaround approaches? Is there a better approach?

Comment: The auto-generated `apply` on the case class's (in this case purely synthetic) companion object doesn't know anything about type members, but you can easily write your own constructor in the companion object that _does_. I've got some examples of this somewhere, but can't find them at the moment…

Comment: @TravisBrown this doesn't seem to be the problem: `val y2: { type T = x.T } = new Y(x)` also doesn't type check with the error message: type mismatch: found `Y`, expected `Y{ type T = u.T }` which expands to `Y{ type T = Int }`.

Answer (score 1):

You've re-used `x` for different things, so from here on I'll call the object instantiated by `val x` "instance x" and the `x: X` used in class Y "parameter x".

"Instance x" is an [anonymous subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762338/scala-abstract-classes-instantiation) of `trait X` with concrete members overriding `trait X`'s abstract members. As a subclass of `X` you can pass it to the constructor for `case class Y` and it will be accepted happily, since as a subclass it *is* an `X`.

It seems to me you expect that `case class Y` will then check *at runtime* to see if the instance of `X` it is passed has overridden `X`'s members, and generate an instance of `Y` whose members have different types depending on what was passed in.

This is emphatically not how Scala works, and would pretty much defeat the purpose of its (static) type system. For example, you wouldn't be able to do anything useful with Y.empty without runtime reflection since it could have any type at all, and at that point you're better off just using a dynamic type system. If you want the benefits of parametricity, free theorems, not needing reflection, etc. then you have to stick to statically determined types (with a small exception for pattern matching). And that's what Scala does here.

What actually happens is that you've told `Y`'s constructor that parameter `x` is an `X`, and so the compiler statically determines that `x.empty`, has the type of `X.empty`, which is abstract type `T`. Scala's inference isn't failing; your types are actually mismatched.

Separately, this doesn't really have anything to do with path-dependent types. Here is a good [walkthrough](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html), but in short, path-dependent types are bound to their parent's instance, not determined dynamically at runtime.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but no, I don't expect a runtime check (for obvious reasons, as you said, this should be checked statically), but instead I'd expect the constructor to have type `A.apply(x0: X): A { type T = x0.T }` instead of just `A.apply(x0: X): A`

Comment: But the first constructor's return type depends on the arguments passed to it at runtime. The compiler has no more way of knowing that `apply` will be passed an instance of `X` with member `type T = Int` than it knows `square(i: Int): Int` will be passed an instance of `Int` with value 8. The objects `apply` emits have members with potentially any type, so you wouldn't be able to safely apply any function to it before performing a runtime type check to be sure you weren't performing arithmetic on a String, or something.

Comment: but this is exactly what Scala promises with path-dependent-types: types that depend on values. Types can't depend on all values, only on vals, not on arbitrary expressions. But this is not the case here. After having read https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/215280/files/paper_1.pdf, I still don't see a theoretical reason why this wouldn't be possible. But the code example also doesn't work in current dotty versions as tested by my coworker. I'm just not sure if there's a theoretical reason behind this or it's just the current Scala implementation which doesn't support it.